# CANON SDK setting the CUSTOM WHITE BALANCE to the SAVED JPG images

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

a friend of mine and I have been fighting to figure out how to extend the **custom white balance** that we could succesfully set on the live view, **to the saved JPG image**. We are using the **Canon SDK 2.1.34** and a EOD 600D camera, programming in C#.

Apparently this is the same problem/procedure connected to applying the Custom Picture modes to the saved image. For us the manual is cryptic. Has anyone a good example on how to achieve that?

Thank you!
Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate from my earlier attempts and question at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957037/setting-custom-liveview-whitebalance-values)

As far as I know this is not correctly supported (nor documented) in the EDSDK, nor have I encountered public workarounds. It also proves hard to get a good contact in Canon (even from within the company) that can help us all out. EOS Utility internally can do it but uses undocumented PTP calls (that could be recorded and reverse engineered).

Unfortunately, your best bet is to either

1. shoot RAW and do custom whitebalancing in post. The as-shot WB is just random.
2. approximate white balance using Color Temperature and custom temperature shift. These can be pushed into JPGs.