# How to set custom white balance or color temperature using canon SDK?!

Tags: c#, canon-sdk

I am gonna use the custom white balance in my project, so I look at the edsdk.cs file and White Balance region. there is color temperature and white paper and click options, but don know how to work with them!
my canon camera is EOS 700D.
in manual wrote that you should take a photo from your target object then set it as white balance! nothing more about image type or size or how to do it with SDK.
is there any one how worked with canon SDK ?! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We're out of luck here on the official SDK (and confirmed by Canon). See also answer and alternatives here: [CANON SDK setting the CUSTOM WHITE BALANCE to the SAVED JPG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931486/canon-sdk-setting-the-custom-white-balance-to-the-saved-jpg-images)